# php mysqli multi_query - ignore second query

Tags: php, mysqli-multi-query

If I execute example.php, everything looks fine, but the **second query** (with a2,b2,c2) is not inserted into my table. I tried more queries, but it is always the second which is "ignored". Is it bug, feature or my mistake..? PHP v5.3.3, MySQL v5.1.73

example.php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
...
$query = "INSERT into mytable (a,b,c) values ('a1','b1','c1');";
$query .= "INSERT into mytable (a,b,c) values ('a2','b2','c2');";
$query .= "INSERT into mytable (a,b,c) values ('a3','b3','c3');";
$query .= "INSERT into mytable (a,b,c) values ('a4','b4','c4')";
...
if ($conn->multi_query($query) === TRUE)
...
```

Comment: Is it the post mistake only, missing the semicolon on the 4th row?

Comment: check for errors then, I don't see any checking here. `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: Your exact code worked for me.

Comment: And is some of a,b or c columns main index or unique. If yes - what about data - may be there is problem.

Comment: 2 Fred -ii-: there is no error at all :(

Comment: 2 Kancho Iliev : unique is "a", but it is not the problem here, im inserting 100 % unique data..

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this?

```
 $query = "INSERT into mytable (a,b,c) values ('a1','b1','c1')";
    $query .= ",('a2','b2','c2')";
    $query .= ",('a3','b3','c3')";
    $query .= ",('a4','b4','c4')";
    ...
    ...

    $query .=";";
if ($conn->multi_query($query) === TRUE)
```

Comment: "Have you tried" is a comment and this is just like changing 4 quarters for a dollar.